# why can't i modify charaters of string using charAt() in java?

Tags: java, string

error:
name.charAt(i)=name.charAt(j);
                           ^
required: variable
found:    value

```
    code

     if(name.charAt(i)>name.charAt(j))
            {
            c=name.charAt(i);
            name.charAt(i)=name.charAt(j);
            name.charAt(j)=c;
            }
```

Comment: Amongst other reasons, because `String`s are immutable.

Comment: Amongst other reasons, because you can't assign a value to a method return, only to a variable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html